# How to avoid reloading data every time navigating to page

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-async

I'm trying to avoid rebuilding `FutureBuilder` in flutter. I have tried solution suggested in below Q's.

[How to parse JSON only once in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51887294/how-to-parse-json-only-once-in-flutter)

[Flutter Switching to Tab Reloads Widgets and runs FutureBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51224420/flutter-switching-to-tab-reloads-widgets-and-runs-futurebuilder)

still my app fires API every time I navigate to that page. Please point me where I'm going wrong.

**Util.dart**

```
//function which call API endpoint and returns Future in list
class EmpNetworkUtils {
    ...
    Future<List<Employees>> getEmployees(data) async {
        List<Employees> emps = [];
        final response = await http.get(host + '/emp', headers: { ... });
        final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
        for (var empdata in responseJson) {
            Employees emp = Employees( ... );
            emps.add(emp);
        }
        return emps;
    }
}
```

**EmpDetails.dart**

```
class _EmpPageState extends State<EmpPage>{
    ...
    Future<List<Employees>>_getAllEmp;
    @override
    initState() {
        _getAllEmp = _getAll();
        super.initState();
    }
    Future <List<Employees>>_getAll() async {
        _sharedPreferences = await _prefs;
        String authToken = AuthSessionUtils.getToken(_sharedPreferences);
        return await EmpNetworkUtils().getEmployees(authToken);
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            appBar: new AppBar( ... ),
            body: Container(
                child: FutureBuilder(
                    future: _getAllEmp,
                    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) { ... }
        )))
    }
}
```

**Update:**
I'm using `bottomNavigationBar` in my app, from which this page is loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling your `getEmployees` function in `initState`, which is meant to be called every time your widget is inserted into the tree. If you want to save the data after calling your function the first time, you will have to have a widget that persists.

An easy implementation would be using an [`InheritedWidget`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html) and a data class:

```dart
class InheritedEmployees extends InheritedWidget {
  final EmployeeData employeeData;

  InheritedEmployees({
    Key key,
    @required Widget child,
  })  : assert(child != null),
        employeeData = EmployeeData(),
        super(key: key, child: child);

  static EmployeeData of(BuildContext context) => (context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(InheritedEmployees) as InheritedEmployees).employeeData;

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(InheritedEmployees old) => false;
}

class EmployeeData {
  List<Employees> _employees;

  Future<List<Employees>> get employees async {
    if (_employees != null) return _employees;
    _sharedPreferences = await _prefs;
    String authToken = AuthSessionUtils.getToken(_sharedPreferences);
    return _employees = await EmpNetworkUtils().getEmployees(authToken);
  }
}
```

Now, you would only have to place your `InheritedEmployees` somewhere that **will not be disposed**, e.g. about your home page, or if you want, even about your `MaterialApp` (`runApp(InheritedEmployees(child: MaterialApp(..));`). This way the data is only fetched once and cached after that. You could also look into [`AsyncMemoizer`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-async_async/AsyncMemoizer-class.html) if that suits you better, but the example I provided should work fine.

Now, you will want to call this `employees` getter in `didChangeDependencies` because your `_EmpPageState` is dependent on `InheritedEmployees` and you need to look that up, which cannot happen in `initState`:

```dart
class _EmpPageState extends State<EmpPage>{
    Future<List<Employees>>_getAllEmp;

    @override
    void didChangeDependencies() {
      _getAllEmp = InheritedEmployees.of(context).employees;
      super.didChangeDependencies();
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            appBar: new AppBar( ... ),
            body: Container(
                child: FutureBuilder(
                    future: _getAllEmp,
                    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) { ... }
        )))
    }
}
```

I mentioned that your `State` is now dependent on your `InheritedWidget`, but that does not really matter as `updateShouldNotify` always returns `false` (there are not going to be any additional builds).

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this. I have few doubts like, 
-- what makes my code different than those solutions (from Q's I linked in this post). 
-- If I want to rebuild the widget is some cases like, If I add new record to emp list, I want to rebuild the widget, or if I want to keep timer, which will rebuild in T seconds, how can I implement that?

Comment: This works great. There are similar pages in my app, where too I want to avoid this. How can I implement that?

Comment: @SuroorAhmmad You can add more objects to your data class.

Comment: You mean adding object to EmployeeData class? That wont help I guess, because I need to fetch data from different APIs.

Comment: @SuroorAhmmad You can give your class a different, more generic name and then have multiple objects, each with a getter. The `InheritedWidget` sits at the top of your app, so you never need to worry about it rebuilding.

Comment: Cool, I'll try that.Is there any way I can force `updateShouldNotify()` return `true` is some conditions, like timer or after adding new item to list.

Comment: @SuroorAhmmad Well, that will not do anything because you are not rebuilding your `InheritedWidget` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49492495/6509751)). You can create a `Stream` and listen to that instead. (You can listen to a timer).

Answer (score 2):

I got another way to solve this issue and apply to my app also

- Apply GetX controller to call API and render response data
- Remove FutureBuilder to call API data

Apply GetX controller to call API data, Like

```
class NavMenuController extends GetxController {

  Api api = new Api();
  var cart = List<NavMenu>().obs;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    // TODO: implement onInit
    getNavMenuData();
    super.onInit();
  }

  Future<List<NavMenu>> getNavMenuData() async {
    var nav_data = await api.getNavMenus();
    if(nav_data!=null) {
      cart.value = nav_data;
    }
    return cart;
  }

}
```

Call API using controller on initState() into desired class

```
class NavMenuDrawer extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NavMenuDrawerState createState() => _NavMenuDrawerState();
}

class _NavMenuDrawerState extends State<NavMenuDrawer> {

  final NavMenuController navMenuController = Get.put(NavMenuController());

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    navMenuController.getNavMenuData();
  }
```

*Remove below FutureBuilder code for calling API, [if you use FutureBuilder/StreamBuilder whatever]*

```
return FutureBuilder<List<NavMenu>>(
      future: api.getNavMenus(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
      
      return ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: ScrollPhysics(),
              itemCount: snapshot.data?.length ?? 0,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Column(
                  children: [
                    ListTile(
                      title: Text("${snapshot.data[index].title}"),
```

**Just use GetX controller to get data, like**

```
return ListView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      physics: ScrollPhysics(),
      itemCount: navMenuController.cart?.length ?? 0,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Column(
          children: [
            ListTile(
              title: Obx(() {
                return Text(
                    "${navMenuController.cart.value[index].title}");
              }),
```

Note : For more info you can search on how to apply GetX